# Order of precedence equation

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Evening all, I am more or less familiar with the order of precedence but this one confuses me and I have an exam tomorrow so yer :d....

Ok so, `6-2/2+5`

Is it:

```
2/2 = 1
1+5 = 6
6-2 = 4
then 4+6 = 10
```

The part that confused me is once you have in step 3 the value 4 then you just add what ever is left in the equation to the total ?

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths and not programming. 

Comment: But watch out: [PEMDAS is wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9h1oqv21Vs).

Comment: @Haidro its in my programming (Python) Exam mate, I don't know what ya wont me to say lol.

Comment: Please don't tag the question with version tags if it is not version specific.

Comment: Closing this seems needless and petty really... why? Order of precedence is used in python isn't it ? dosen't it help in programming ?. tad strange guys... are some of us on a power trip maybe ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `(2/2)` = `1`   *division is performed first*
2. `(6-(1))` = `5` *+ and - have **equal** precedence, so we go left to right, hence 6 - (2/2) is done first*
3. `(5)+5` = `10` *finish it by doing addition*

Comment: AAAAAAAhhhh left to right if equal precedence awesome :D

Comment: @bennyboy yep, also a question on boolean logic is likely to come up in your exam i.e: `((aBool and bBool) or (cBool and dBool or not eBool))`

Answer (score 3):

No, it is:

6-2/2+5 
=  6 -  2/2   + 5 
= (6 - (2/2)) + 5 
= (6 -    1 ) + 5 
=  5          + 5 
= 10

/ and * before + and -. In case of equal precedence it evaluates from left to right.

For more details you might want to consider the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) (just scroll down to the end).

Comment: Im sure you are correct however your answer confuses me lol

Comment: Why does it confuse you?